# How to identify a yes/no question

Tags: questions

Is there any pattern or heuristic that can be used to identify a yes/no question, with reasonable accuracy?

Comment: The questions without interrogative are 'yes/no questions.

Comment: @aswaaks - do you include questions about the word *Why*?

Comment: Did you meet him? - Yes / No question.  When did you meet him? -  Question with the interrogative.

Comment: When you reply to a question  with Yes or No,  that question is Yes/No question.

Comment: Can the question reasonably be answered with "yes" or "no"?  If so then it's a "yes/no" question.

Comment: Which do you prefer, "yes" or "no"?

Comment: @JHCL-  Heh!  SmartA$$!  ;-)

Comment: Yes-no questions don't begin with a question word such as where/when/why etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Yes/No* questions in formal English have the following characteristics:

1. A rising intonation at the end of the question; in print, the question mark.
2. An inversion of the subject and the first auxiliary verb. E.g,
   ***You have*** lived in New York. ~ **Have you** lived in New York?
   If there is no auxiliary verb at hand, *Do*-Support provides one:
   ***You lived*** on 37th Street. ~ **Did you live** on 37th Street?

That's it for Y/N questions; they're the simplest.
*Wh*-questions start off from Y/N questions and add an interrogative *Wh*-word.
There are of course many other ways to ask questions. Aren't there?

Comment: Of course, "You have lived in New York"  or "You lived on 37th Street" is sufficient to be a yes/no question if a rising tone is heard at the end.

Comment: Right. That's one of the other ways. But the OQ asked for reasonable accuracy. Meeting both criteria increases accuracy.